# Hacking a "line-below" version of indent-relative

Tags: elisp, indentation

From indent.el:

```
(defun indent-relative (&optional unindented-ok)
  "Space out to under next indent point in previous nonblank line.
An indent point is a non-whitespace character following whitespace.
The following line shows the indentation points in this line.
    ^         ^    ^     ^   ^           ^      ^  ^    ^
If the previous nonblank line has no indent points beyond the
column point starts at, `tab-to-tab-stop' is done instead, unless
this command is invoked with a numeric argument, in which case it
does nothing.

See also `indent-relative-maybe'."
  (interactive "P")
  (if (and abbrev-mode
       (eq (char-syntax (preceding-char)) ?w))
      (expand-abbrev))
  (let ((start-column (current-column))
    indent)
    (save-excursion
      (beginning-of-line)
      (if (re-search-backward "^[^\n]" nil t)
      (let ((end (save-excursion (forward-line 1) (point))))
        (move-to-column start-column)
        ;; Is start-column inside a tab on this line?
        (if (> (current-column) start-column)
        (backward-char 1))
        (or (looking-at "[ \t]")
        unindented-ok
        (skip-chars-forward "^ \t" end))
        (skip-chars-forward " \t" end)
        (or (= (point) end) (setq indent (current-column))))))
    (if indent
    (let ((opoint (point-marker)))
      (delete-region (point) (progn (skip-chars-backward " \t") (point)))
      (indent-to indent 0)
      (if (> opoint (point))
          (goto-char opoint))
      (move-marker opoint nil))
      (tab-to-tab-stop))))
```

How would I modify this function so that it aligns the current line with the indentation point in the **next**, as opposed to the previous, line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on erikstokes suggestion, I've come up with a working solution.

edit: I also used code from

http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/04/02/move-current-line-up-or-down/

```
(defun move-line-down ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((col (current-column)))
    (save-excursion
      (forward-line)
      (transpose-lines 1))
    (forward-line)
    (move-to-column col)))

(defun move-line-up ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((col (current-column)))
    (save-excursion
      (forward-line)
      (transpose-lines -1))
    (move-to-column col)))

;; Indent relative, but works for the line below rather than above 
(defun indent-relative-below ()
  (interactive)
  (move-line-down)
  (indent-relative)
  (move-line-up))
(global-set-key  (kbd "C-;") 'indent-relative-below)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to swap the current line with the next one, use `indent-relative` and then swap back:

```
(defun indent-relative-below ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (next-line)
    (transpose-lines 1)
    (previous-line)
    (indent-relative)
    (transpose-lines 1)
    )
  (end-of-line)
  )
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Though that may have something to do with my use of the "evil" plugin.

Comment: You could start Emacs with `emacs -Q`  to see if it's something in your config.